# Angular Promise.all in timeout event not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following issue using Angular 6. What I'm trying to do is to wait some promises to be resolved in order to do something else. Here is what I have and it's working:

AppService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {

  p1: Promise<any>;
  p2: Promise<any>;

  constructor() { 
    this.getPromise1();
    this.getPromise2();
  }

  getPromise1() {
    this.p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(true);
    });
  }

  getPromise2() {
    this.p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 5000);
    });
  }
}
```

AppComponent.ts

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private appSrvc: AppService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    Promise.all([this.appSrvc.p1, this.appSrvc.p2])
      .then(values => { 
          console.log(values);
          //If all promises resolved then execute something here
      })
      .catch(error => { 
          console.log(error.message)
      });
  }
}
```

Now when I edit the following it's not working:

AppService.ts

```
 constructor() { 
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getPromise1();
      this.getPromise2();
    }, 1000);
  }
  ...
```

When I call the same promises from another method with a timeout event they don't work and I can't understand why. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, code from `ngAfterViewInit` is executed right away (at least, most likely within a second), while your service's promises become initialized only after a second (`setTimeout` being async). Therefore, when `Promise.all([this.appSrvc.p1, this.appSrvc.p2])` is executed, said promises are still null. What exactly are you trying to accomplish / what is the purpose of `setTimeout` here?

Comment: Ok I understand but how can I resolve this problem? Where do I need to have the Promise.all in my component in order to wait the promises until they resolved

Comment: You didn't answer that question at the end of my comment: what are you trying to accomplish? `Promise.all` already does what you need, it waits until promises are resolved before doing something else.

Comment: I think you should switch to observable. Promise is concept that has fundamentally one application making ajax request. It was not design to do anything else.

Comment: setTimeout is just to emulate the time that is spent for data retrieval from other services and different calculations

Comment: @Bad_Pan You're already accomplishing this with `setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 5000);` (within your second promise). That's where it should be: within the promise code, not outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is:

1. `AppService` constructor is called at the moment of it's injection into the module
2. Few ms after that the `AppComponent` is injected
3. About 100 ms later `AppComponent=>ngAfterViewInit()` is called

When you set the timeout, the initialization of those two promises is postponed 1000ms. At that point your `AppComponent=>ngAfterViewInit()` is already done and values of those two what-will-be promises is actually `undefined`. To fix this you need to sync those two events, thus calling `AppService.initialize()` from `AppComponent` will do the trick but you also must make it async.

Here's an example how you can sync this:

```
getPromise1() {
    if(!this.p1) {
        return this.p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(true);
        });
    }
    return this.p1;
}
getPromise2() {
    if(!this.p2) {
        return this.p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 5000);
        });
    }
    return this.p2;
}
```

And then at the call site:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    Promise.all([this.appSrvc.getPromise1(), this.appSrvc.getPromise2()])
        .then(values => { 
                console.log(values);
                //If all promises resolved then execute something here
        })
        .catch(error => { 
                console.log(error.message)
        });
}
```

Comment: Huh... `setTimeout` does not return a Promise?

Comment: You're right, i've switched to $timeout of AngularJS, whoops

Comment: @Jeto I think i've added an answer after you already made quite the same in the comment of the question. If you make it in an answer i will remove mine.

Comment: Since there's no DOM reading, I think `ngOnInit` is more appropriate

Comment: @maljukan It's OK!